# package: avoid importing the entire module when importing only one of its members into __init__.py

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

Sorry if the title is not very clear but I failed to summarize well.
I'm experimenting with packages and I'm in this situation:

```
$:~/project$ tree
.
├── first_mod.py
└── first_package
    ├── __init__.py
    └── sub_package
        ├── __init__.py
        └── second_mod.py
```

In the first `__init__.py` inside `first_package` dir I specifies this content:

```
from first_package.sub_package.second_mod import function
```

(obviously in the module `second_mod` there is a function called `function`)

If I open an interpreter in the dir `project` and import `first_package` and then try to see what it contains using tab autocompletion, in addition to the `function` the `sub_package` is also listed.

```
>>> import first_package
>>> first_package.                             [tab]
first_package.function(    first_package.sub_package
```

The question is: is it inevitable that `sub_package` is also shown as the content of `first_package` when I import only `function` in the `__init__.py`?

Comment: questions like these are hard to answer, because IDEs/REPLs can do all kinds of black magic to do things that they'll assume will make your life easier - such as parse directories for modules that might be there. If you want to know what python's opinion is, you should ask python: run `dir(first_package)` and check if `sub_package` is in there. If it is, it got loaded somehow. If it isn't then your IDE was lying to you.

Comment: Yes, `sub_package` is there with dir too (however, I did the test in the question just with the python repl, not with an IDE).
However, in the meantime I thought that maybe it's the right behavior (maybe) because in this way you can import everything that interests you regardless of what is written in `__init__.py`

Comment: but I think I'm confusing myself about what you can import and what's already imported...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior at hand can be explained with a short rundown of what happens when you import a module `baz` with a statement like `import foo.bar.baz`.

#### 1: importing parent modules

Before `baz` can be imported, `bar` needs to be there. And before `bar` can be imported, `foo` needs to be there - there is no way for python to reach `baz` via a shortcut.

#### 2: running `__init__.py` files

Every package that is imported along the up to `baz` has an `__init__.py` file, which is executed.

#### 3: loading encountered modules into `sys.modules`

When a folder is imported as a package, all python files in it are imported as modules (excluding `__init__.py` files, which can be imagined to be stand-in for the package itself). They will be loaded into `sys.modules` and are accessible to the package objects (which in this case are `foo`, ``bar`, and` baz`).

---

And that's pretty much it, the gritty details can be looked up [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

In your example, two `import` statements got executed (one by you and one when `first_package/__init__.py` was run), but only the first one is necessary to explain what happened. When you imported `first_package`, the third step loads all modules that are part of the package. This includes `sub_package`, and there is no way around it using the standard import mechanisms.

Running

```py
del first_pacakge.sub_package
```

will remove it from the object in case you only care about that, but it won't unload it and it will still be in `sys.modules`.

Comment: I accept this answer as correct because it is very logical and complete and therefore provides me with a motivation that is easy for me to recognize and remember.
The only thing I tried to do was to test to see if I understood correctly and removed the content from `./project/first_package/__init__py`, I tried to restart the interpreter, import again `first_package` control its contents.
In this case there is no trace of `sub_package`:
`>>> dir(first_package)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']`

Comment: I'll go over my setup once more and try to explain what you found.